# How do I change date range on candlestick chart in javascript

Tags: javascript, api, plotly, finance

So far I have a candlestick graph but the user cannot customise the date range to do this I would need to change the api url [this](https://support.twelvedata.com/en/articles/5214728-getting-historical-data) is the documentation for my api.

I want it to be done through buttons to have the option of 1 day, 5 days, 1 month, 6 months, 1 year, 5 years, and all time. But I don't know how to make pressing the buttons update the api url to display the new graph. Is there a way to do this?

this is the code:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Candlestick Chart Example</title>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

<script>
    var symbol = 'AAPL';
    var interval = '1day';
    var apikey = 'apikeyiset';

    var url = 'https://api.twelvedata.com/time_series?symbol=' + symbol + '&interval=' + interval + '&apikey=' + apikey;

    Plotly.d3.json(url, function(data) {
    var trace = {
        x: data.values.map(function(d) { return d.datetime; }),
        open: data.values.map(function(d) { return d.open; }),
        high: data.values.map(function(d) { return d.high; }),
        low: data.values.map(function(d) { return d.low; }),
        close: data.values.map(function(d) { return d.close; }),
        type: 'candlestick',
    };

    var layout = {
        title: symbol + ' Candlestick Chart',
    };

    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [trace], layout);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>`
```

I know how to add buttons in html but not sure how to make them change the api url.

Comment: I'm afraid that your question, as it is now, is too broad. I'm not sure if you don't know anything about using buttons in javascript. If this is the case you may search online for a tutorial on javascript button `onclick` or click event. In any case, you should add the buttons and click event handlers and if you're stuck on a more specific issue, update our question or ask a new one.